# I want to find out more about Raab Schwalbe Reg SX-AAG

Tags: aviation-history

According to the records on the web, Raab Schwalbe 11 reg SX-AAG was built in Greece in 1935 and sold abroad in 1937.

I know that it was destroyed in a crash on landing in Palestine but I am not sure when that happened.  I originally thought it would have been in 1936 but it may have been later. The picture was taken in Palestine before it crashed.

Does anybody know more about the history of SX-AAG?[image]

Comment: Could you summarize which sources you have already consulted in your search for information?

Comment: The only information I found on the web came from http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_SX-.html